# why this regex is not working with find command on linux

Tags: regex, linux

I am trying to execute this command

```
find /home/scratch/test_cases/deleted/2nmW1wDfb5/ -iregex '.*/moodys_munis_full_refresh_flat_file_\d+.zip' -type f
```

It cannot find any file but the file is there when I do ls

```
ls /home/scratch/test_cases/deleted/2nmW1wDfb5/moodys_munis_full_refresh_flat_file_2.zip
```

Result is

```
/home/scratch/test_cases/deleted/2nmW1wDfb5/moodys_munis_full_refresh_flat_file_2.zip
```

Comment: Try: `-iregex '.*/moodys_munis_full_refresh_flat_file_[0-9]*\.zip'`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find ... -iregex '.*[0-9]+.zip' -type f
```

instead. Or run

```
find -regextype --help
find: Unknown regular expression type '--help'; valid types are 'findutils-default', 'awk', 'egrep', 'ed', 'emacs', 'gnu-awk', 'grep', 'posix-awk', 'posix-basic', 'posix-egrep', 'posix-extended', 'posix-minimal-basic', 'sed'.
```

to get a list of known -regextypes on your system, and try

```
find ... -regextype sed -iregex '.*[0-9]+.zip' -type f
```

and the other options, if you don't know, what which style stands for.

On my system, \d doesn't work with any of the options:

```
for rt in "findutils-default" "awk" "egrep" "ed" "emacs" "gnu-awk" "grep" "posix-awk" "posix-basic" "posix-egrep" "posix-extended" "posix-minimal-basic" "sed"
do 
   echo -n $rt" "
   find . -type f -regextype $rt -iregex '.*ro.*2\d+.scala'
   echo
done

findutils-default 
awk 
egrep 
ed 
emacs 
gnu-awk 
grep 
posix-awk 
posix-basic 
posix-egrep 
posix-extended 
posix-minimal-basic 
sed
```

while rectangle braces are understood by about 50% of them:

```
for rt in "findutils-default" "awk" "egrep" "ed" "emacs" "gnu-awk" "grep" "posix-awk" "posix-basic" "posix-egrep" "posix-extended" "posix-minimal-basic" "sed"
do 
   echo -n $rt" "
   find . -type f -regextype $rt -iregex '.*ro.*2[0-9]+.scala'
   echo
done

findutils-default ./rot1-25.scala

awk ./rot1-25.scala

egrep ./rot1-25.scala

ed 
emacs ./rot1-25.scala

gnu-awk ./rot1-25.scala

grep 
posix-awk ./rot1-25.scala

posix-basic 
posix-egrep ./rot1-25.scala

posix-extended ./rot1-25.scala

posix-minimal-basic 
sed
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried with sed and [0-9]+ worked but then [0-9]{5} doesnt work. Since the option to enter file matching pattern will be available to users, they can enter any regex. Whay {5} doesnt work?

Comment: @Imran: Have you seen the for-loops to test the -regexp-types against a regex? Sometimes you have to mask `\{5\}`, some will not understand it at all. "egrep" works without masking, "sed" for example with masking.